# Network Video Recorder

Tags: home-security, nvr

My 3-year-old Lorex NVR is dead.  I have six POE HD IP cameras: Lorex models

- LNB2153
- LND2152
- MCNB2151

I want to get an 8-16 channel NVR that will work with those, and that will also support newer IP cameras.  Recommendations?